# Universal Cover of Hawaiian Earring

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I need to prove that [Hawaiian Earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) has no [universal cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers). By 'universal' I mean all other covers are below it. For instance if $Y$ is a covering space of $X$ and $Z$ is an another covering space of $X$, then $Y$ is also covering space of $Z$. In this sense $Y$ is the universal covering space.

By Hawaiian Earring I mean $X=\bigcup_n C_n$ where $C_n$ is a circle with center $(1/n,0)$ and radius $1/n$, i.e. $C_n=\lbrace x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2 \: | \: (x-1/n)^2 +y^2 = 1/n^2 \rbrace $.

Let's define $g_k:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $g_k(x,y)= (\frac{x}{n^{(k+1)/n}}, \frac{y}{n^{(k+1)/n}})$. Ofc it's homeomorphism cuz it's just multiplication by a constant. Moreover I am able to prove that $g_k(C_t)=C_{t+k+1} $, thus $g_k(X)=g_k(\bigcup_n C_n)=\bigcup_{k+1} = X_k$ where $X_k=\bigcup_{n>k} C_n$. So $g_k (X)= X_k$.

Now I gonna to construct covering space of $X$ and then show that it ain't universal cover. But from this point I don't know how to begin with.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected

Comment: Every cover of the Hawaiian earring space will have to evenly cover some neighborhood of the origin. Every neighborhood of the origin will contain (infinitely many)  loops. This means intuitively that the cover is not simply connected, so it can't be a universal covering space. This argument can be made precise.